# How can I take a log snapshot of device information?

Tags: applications, logging

If I experienced a problem with my phone — for example, if I cannot make calls, or cannot download or watch videos — I would like to take gather a log of device information including which cell site I was on, the current signal strength, GPS location, the device IP address, DNS server IP, memory usage and CPU usage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished several ways.

Since you sound very interested in your tech - but maybe not all-about-the-coding - my thought is to grab something like zooper widgets and build a widget with all of the data you want. It can easily grab most of what you're looking for with no coding required, plus you get to learn a little something about your OS and gear.

With that homemade widget on your screen of choice, do a screenshot and you've got your info all in one place.